# Encode and Decode enum in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, nscoder

I have a `enum` in my Swift class and a variable declared. I need to encode and decode it using `NSCoder`. There are a lot of questions about this saying that I should use `rawValue`. `Enum` is declared the following way:

```
enum ConnectionType {
    case Digital, PWM
}
```

But in Swift 1.2 there is no such initialiser. How do do that in Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define a "raw type" for the enum, e.g.

```
enum ConnectionType : Int {
    case Digital, PWM
}
```

Then you can encode it with

```
aCoder.encodeInteger(type.rawValue, forKey: "type")
```

and decode with

```
type = ConnectionType(rawValue: aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("type")) ?? .Digital
```

where the nil-coalescing operator `??` is used to supply a default value
if the decoded integer is not valid for the enumeration.